# StringArrays As A List<> Items -> How Prevent Changing All Items By Changing One Item(predefined string array)

Tags: c#, list, arrays

please see these codes :

```
    List<string[]> items_1 = new List<string[]>();
    string[] item = new string[] { "item_id_for_sell", "item_title", "item_id_main", "item_amount", "item_del_id" };
    items_1.Add(item);
    item[0] = "1";
    item[1] = "1";
    item[2] = "1";
    item[3] = "1";
    item[4] = "1";
    items_1.Add(item);
    item[0] = "2";
    item[1] = "2";
    item[2] = "2";
    item[3] = "2";
    item[4] = "2";
    items_1.Add(item);
```

i am so confused about this list.
why all string arrays inside that list have "2" value at last?
how can i prevent that list to update itself by updating item (string array)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding a reference to the same array three times, so changing the *contents* of the array will indeed allow that change to be seen however you get at it. It's important that you understand that the list doesn't contain the array itself - it contains *references*. See my article about [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more information.

You probably just want a new array each time:

```
List<string[]> items_1 = new List<string[]>();
string[] item = { "item_id_for_sell", "item_title",
                  "item_id_main", "item_amount", "item_del_id" };
items_1.Add(item);
item = new string[] { "1", "1", "1", "1", "1" };
items_1.Add(item);
item = new string[] { "2", "2", "2", "2", "2" };
items_1.Add(item);
```

However, I'd urge you to reconsider whether an array of strings is *really* the best format here. Why not create an `Item` class with properties `Id`, `Title`, `Main`, `Amount` and `DelId` (whatever that means)? Then you can create a `List<Item>` which will be much easier to work with.